# How do you do inheritance in JavaScript without sharing the same instance of the super class between all instances of the sub class?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming, prototype-oriented

I noticed that every tutorial on how to do JavaScript inheritance does this:

```
SubClass.prototype = new SuperClass();
```

But this will create a single instance of the super class and share it among all the instances of the sub class.

The problem is that I would like to pass arguments to the super class constructor which originate from arguments passed to the sub class.

In Java this would be done like this:

```
class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  public SubClass(String s) {
    super(s);
  }
}
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
function SubClass(args) {
  this.constructor.prototype = new SuperClass(args);
}
```

But this will not work. So is there a way to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: You are not really creating an "instance". You are creating another object.

Comment: Stop resisting - start enjoying ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800964/benefits-of-prototypal-inheritance-over-classical

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do c69, but I have no idea how.

Comment: What's the difference between creating an instance and creating an object ThiefMaster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I have always done it.

```
// Parent object
function Thing(options)
{ 
    //do stuff
}

Thing.prototype.someMethod = function(){
    // some stuff
   console.log('hello');
}

// child object which inherits from the parent
function OtherThing(options)
{       
    Thing.call(this, options);
    // do stuff for otherthing
}

OtherThing.prototype = new Thing();

OtherThing.prototype.someMethod = function(){
   // call things original function
   Thing.prototype.someMethod.call(this);

   // now do anything different
   console.log('other thing says hi');
}


var testObj = new OtherThing();
    testObj.someMethod();
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/F3m4d/)**

Answer (score 6):

A common pattern is the following:

A temporary constructor is created, which inherits from the parent constructor's prototype. The child constructor's prototype is then set to an instance of the temporary constructor.

```
function inherits(Child, Parent) {
    var Tmp = function() {};
    Tmp.prototype = Parent.prototype;
    Child.prototype = new Tmp();
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}
```

Inside the child constructor you then have to call the parent's constructor:

```
function Child(a, b, c) {
    Parent.call(this, a, b);
}

inherits(Child, Parent);

// add prototype properties here
```

Inside this function call, `this` will refer to the new object which gets created when you call `new Child()`, hence, whatever initialization is performed inside `Parent`, it is applied to the new object we pass.

Comment: I don't understand why the "inherits" function is necessary. Why not do as http://stackoverflow.com/a/8736207/652460 suggests and do everything as usual except for using the "Parent.call(this, args)" line?

I know that I asked for a way around creating new instances but from what I'm gathering, the state of the parent class instance will be different for different instances of sub class.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. But anyways, doing something like `Child.prototype = new Parent()` works as long as `Parent` does not expect (requires) any arguments. In addition, it makes the code a bit cleaner/clearer IMO, but that might be subjective. Major libraries such as the Google Closure Library and YUI provide such a function.

Comment: @mtanti I was wondering that to. Without the temporary constructor (Tmp) you will end up calling the parent constructor twice - Child.prototype=new Parent(), function Child(a,b,c){Parent.call(this, a, b);}, and in the first instance you won't have any parameters to pass onto the parent constructor.

Answer (score 2):

> But this will create a single instance of the super class and share it among all the instances of the sub class.

Yes, that's how inheritance works in JavaScript.

> So is there a way to do this in JavaScript?

Not without horribly subverting/twising/misusing the existing paradigm. I recommend taking a different approach to implementing whatever you're aiming for.

Comment: But is there a way to avoid rewriting code to initialize the variables in the super class every time I write a new sub class? What if I write sub sub classes? Will I have to initialize all the variables of all the ancestors?

Comment: Instead of variables in the super class, it sounds like you should use _functions_ that the sub class can call. Perhaps even allow for a no-arg version (which the super class would use) and a >0-arg version the sub classes would use.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would to get rid of the class-like (but not class-based) inheritance that involves the use of constructor.

Use Object.create along with Object.defineProperties. This is based on the native prototype-based inheritance system that JavaScript follows internally.

You can find more information on it on MDN and ECMAScript specs.

These methods however works only in ECMAScript 5 compliant browsers. This excludes IE8 and older. Fortunately, IE9 supports it and as does the rest of the major browsers. In long run, I think this would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

With [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) it is now possible to simplify "temporary constructor" pattern. Here's an example right from the doc - [Classical inheritance with Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#classical_inheritance_with_object.create):

```
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);

//If you don't set Rectangle.prototype.constructor to Rectangle,
//it will take the prototype.constructor of Shape (parent).
//To avoid that, we set the prototype.constructor to Rectangle (child).
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();

console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle?', rect instanceof Rectangle); // true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape?', rect instanceof Shape); // true
rect.move(1, 1); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
```