# Why would these three lines of code result in the definition of a Javascript "class"?

Tags: javascript

The [Javascript microlibrary augment.js](https://github.com/javascript/augment) is sometimes used to include OOP-like features in Javascript code. Despite working with Javascript on a daily basis I am still somewhat naive about the inner workings of the language, so I often rely on or borrow from patterns from other libraries to avoid pitfalls.

One function in the `augment.js` library is `defclass`, which is quite short:

```
augment.defclass = function (prototype) {
        var constructor = prototype.constructor;
        constructor.prototype = prototype;
        return constructor;
    };
```

My question is: how is this anything like defining a class? It looks like all it does is 1) set the `prototype` of the input's `constructor` to be the input itself, and then 2) return the `constructor`. What does that have to do with defining a class (or something like a class)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how is this anything like defining a class?

The question you need to answer first is: What is a class in Javascript?

From: [Object vs Class vs Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525450/object-vs-class-vs-function)

> As you must already be aware by now there are no classes in
>   JavaScript. Instead functions in JavaScript may be made to behave like
>   constructors by preceding a function call with the new keyword. This
>   is known as the constructor pattern.

From: [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://books.google.ie/books/about/JavaScript.html?id=F9ybAgAAQBAJ&hl=en) Douglas Crockford, O'Reilly Media, 8 May 2008, page 29

> If a function is invoked with the `new` prefix, then a new object will
>   be created with a hidden link to the value of the function's `prototype`
>   member, and `this` will be bound to that new object.

So again there are no classes - you have functions that can be invoked with `new`. If those functions have a `prototype` property, then the new objects created are inheriting from that prototype.

Everything you need to do to define a Javascript function to be used as a constructor is setting the properties you want instances to inherit on its prototype property and (as you pointed out in your question) `augment.defclass` is doing that.

The reason for having such a function has been already explained by minitech in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

A class defined like this:

```
var Thing = augment.defclass({
    constructor: function () {
        this.x = 5;
    },
    getX: function () {
        return this.x;
    }
});
```

A typical JavaScript constructor:

```
function Thing() {
    this.x = 5;
}

Thing.prototype.getX = function () {
    return this.x;
};
```

They both have the same effect, but the `defclass` version looks more familiar to users of other languages. One extracts the constructor from the prototype, and the other puts the prototype on the constructor.