# Return function in object not working

Tags: javascript, function, object

I'm trying to return an object with a function inside. When I call it, I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: config.something is not a function

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

#### JSFiddle

```js
function config() {
  function something() {
    console.log('something');
  }
  return {
    something: something
  };
}

config.something();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Description

Since `config` is a function not an object you need to call/execute it, this then returns the object that you can call `.something` on.

### Code for Function

```js
function config() {
  function something() {
    console.log('something');
  }
  return {
    something: something
  };
}

config().something();
```

### Code for Object

```js
var config = {
  something: function() {
    console.log('something');
  }
};

config.something();
```

More resources:

- https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e#.eqdstb1l6
- [Object vs Class vs Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525450/object-vs-class-vs-function)
- https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e#.eqdstb1l6
- https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+functions+vs+objects&oq=javascript+functions+vs+&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.4688j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Do you know of any resources that speak more about this?

Comment: @Jessica add to answr