# Accessing a property inside a method in javascript

Tags: javascript

In the my script **document** is an object and **querySelector** is a method. But what is innerHTML? Is it a property?

```
document.querySelector('#heading').innerHTML = "Hello world";
```

If it is a property, how i can write my own properties and methods like that?

Comment: Such beginner questions like this must have been asked many times on SO. Why asking again?

Comment: Refer this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Yes it is a property. Here is a small example. https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_object_method

Comment: It's a property of the *object returned by the method*. Just write a method that returns an object.

Comment: Ok, then it means innerHTML is a property inside querySelector?

Answer (score -1):

the answer is yes. these are predefined objects, methods, and properties.

to [create an object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp): `var o = {}`;

to [create a function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp): `var f = function(){};`;

since JS is a [dynamic programming language](http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2017/09/python-vs-c-real-answer.html) you can always add functions and properties at any time.

in JS [functions and objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525450/object-vs-class-vs-function) are the same. so to both adding another function:
`f.add` or `o.add = function(a, b){return a+b};`

and to both adding a property `f.name` or `o.name = 'I'm Batman'`