# Do methods have to be within an object to be chained together?

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor

I'm trying to understand how chaining functions work in JavaScript. I have two examples:

First

```
    class Arithmetic {
      constructor() {
        this.value = 0;
      }
      add(value) {
        this.value = this.value + value;
        return this;
      }
     subtract(value) {
     this.value = this.value - value;
     return this;
     }
   }
```

You can do chain the methods by instantiating `let a = new arithmetic();` and `a.add(3).subtract(4);`

Second

```
var zappo = function(selector) {
  var el;

  var obj = {
    getEl(selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
    },
    addClass(className){
    el.classList.add(className);
    return this;
    }
  }

  el = getEl(selector);
  return obj;
}
```

I can chain these methods by `zappo(#main).addClass("green").addClass("red");`

My question is why is the first constructor function able to chain functions without having the methods within an object whereas the second function requires all the methods to be within an object?

Comment: You're able to chain because the methods are returning a reference to itself `return this;`, the hidden question Classes vs Objects can be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525450/object-vs-class-vs-function#17525749

Comment: In your second example, `getEl` should not be a method of the object at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is why is the first constructor function able to chain functions without having the methods within an object...

They methods *are* in the object, because the object inherits from its prototype, and the methods are defined on the prototype.

> Do methods have to be within an object to be chained together?

By definition, methods are only accessible on objects (or JavaScript's primitives that effectively but not literally get promoted to objects), because otherwise we call them functions, not methods.

Method chaining isn't anything special. All you're doing when you do `x.a().b()` is calling `a` on `x` and then calling `b` on whatever it is `a` returns. In your `class` example, each method does `return this` so each returns the object it was called on. But you can just as easily use `x.a().b()` when `a` returns an object that **isn't** `x`. It's actually very common. Example:

```
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener(/*...*/);
```

`querySelector` doesn't return `document`, it returns the element that was found. The above assumes an element will be found and returned (rather than `querySelector` returning `null`) and calls `addEventListener` on that element.

Comment: What would be an example of method chaining from a non-constructor where the methods are not in an object?

Comment: @Kevvv - The methods are in an object regardless. I think I may have misread your title. I read it as "the *same* object" but what you wrote was "*an* object." I've updated the answer slightly to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't require it:

```
 class zappo {
  constructor(selector) {
    this.el = document.querySelector(selector);
  }

  addClass(className){
   this.el.classList.add(className);
   return this;
 }
}
```