# How is it possible to add an array argument to a constructor for an object, thus to give each object its own array?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have a object constructor where each objects has its own array?

I am have trouble figuring out the syntax if so.

Right now I am creating objects and a separate array to co-aside the object(waiters) array.

```
function Waiter (name, orders[]) {
    this.name = name;
    this.orders = orders;
}

// Constructor for waiter object
function Waiter (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

// Waiter objects
var waiterOne = new Waiter('Timo');
var waiterTwo = new Waiter('Lucian');
var waiterThree = new Waiter('Arpi');


// Array to store waiter object 
var waiters = [
    waiterOne,
    waiterTwo,
    waiterThree
];

// Count so that the same number of arrays are create as waiters
var countWaiterOrders = waiters.length;

// Creating a order array for each waiter object
for(var i = 0; i <= countWaiterOrders; i++){
    var order = [i];
}
```

Getting error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Is the error message I get when trying to pass an array to the constructor.

The desired result would just be that each Waiter object has its own array for orders.

ex:

```
console.log(waiters[0]);

Waiter {name: "Timo", orders: []}
```

Comment: Change `order[]` to `order` in the method definition here `function Waiter (name, order)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly question I was just a bit stuck for a while you assign the value to an empty array not the argument.

//Waiter constructor

```
function Waiter (name, order) {
    this.name = name;
    this.order = [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I'm missing something, but it seems that you could just use something like this:

```
class Waiter {
      constructor(name) {
        this.name = name
        this.orders = []
      }
    }
```

What you are doing here is creating a class `Waiter` to which you pass a `name` as variable.

You can create a `Waiter` like so: `var waiterOne = new Waiter('Tim')`.

This would then allow you to use `waiterOne.name` or `waiterOne.orders`, as the array of orders is created in the constructor of the class.

If you wanted to store all your waiters in the array, the good method may be to create a collection class called `Waiters` - This could be useful if you wanted to do some operations on the whole collection of your Waiters.

Comment: The current syntax will allow you to use `waiterOne.name` as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. I just wanted to mention this, so it's clear that he can still use `.name` on the object.

Comment: Thanks @Tigger, Irek  So if later I want to be pushing orders to the individual waiters.order.Array. Would it be better to use a class or an Object?

Comment: @Liam : Suggest having a read of [Object vs Class vs Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525450/object-vs-class-vs-function) - Please read the comments too - and decide what is best for you.