# Clarification on Prototype and Object.create pattern

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, javascript-inheritance

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Animal</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" >

            var Animal = function () {
                return {
                    sayName: function (name) {
                        alert("My name is " + name);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Animal object
            var animalObj = new Animal();
            // Cat1 inherits from animalObj using prototype pattern.
            var Cat1 = function () {
                var obj = {
                    run: function () {
                        alert("I am running...");
                    },
                };
                obj.prototype = animalObj;
                return obj;

            }

            // Cat1 inherits from animalObj using Object.create pattern.
            var Cat2 = function () {
                var obj = Object.create(animalObj);
                obj.run = function () {
                    alert("I am running...");
                };
                return obj;

            }
            var cat1 = new Cat1();
            cat1.prototype.sayName("Cat1");
            cat1.run();

            var cat2 = new Cat2();
            cat2.sayName("Cat2");
            cat2.run();

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a Animal class. It has `sayName` method.

Cat1 inherits from Animal using `Prototype` pattern.

Cat2 inherits from Animal using `Object.create` pattern.

In the case of cat1, is it possible to invoke sayName like `cat1.sayName("Cat1")` instead of `cat1.prototype.sayName("Cat1");`?

In the case of cat2, is it possible to define the Cat2's own properties and functions and then inherit the Animal like

```
var Cat2 = function () {
       var obj = {
           run: function () {
               alert("I am running...");
           },
       };

       // Here I want obj inherits Animal. How can I do that?
       return obj;
}
```

So that I can have a clean structure. I doesn't want to use like

```
obj.run = function () {
    alert("I am running...");
};
```

Please clarify.

Comment: You have to invoke `cat1.prototype.sayName` so oddly, because this isn't prototypal inheritance

Comment: `Object.create` doesn't support multiple inheritance. But you can inherit from several prototypes by [concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800964/benefits-of-prototypal-inheritance-over-classical)

Comment: cat1.prototype is treated as a normal property right? So how can I inherit Animal in Cat1

Answer (score -1):

Replace line

```
obj.prototype = animalObj;
```

with

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, animalObj);
```

And you can call

```
cat1.sayName("Cat1");
```