# How does JavaScript's prototypal Inheritance work?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I want to know how JavaScript's Prototypal inheritance works.When we are creating an object with the new keyword the object's  `__proto__`  is set to `Constructor_Function.prototype` .

But I don't understand why I am getting this Output.

My code :

```
function SimpleFunction(){}

let obj = new SimpleFunction();

console.dir(obj);
```

Output :

```
SimpleFunction {}
    [[Prototype]]: Object
        constructor: ƒ SimpleFunction()
        [[Prototype]]: Object
            constructor: ƒ Object()
            hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
            isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
            propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
            toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
            toString: ƒ toString()
            valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
            __defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
            __defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
            __lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
            __lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
            __proto__: Object
                constructor: ƒ SimpleFunction()
                [[Prototype]]: Object
                constructor: ƒ Object()
                hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
                isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
                propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
                toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
                toString: ƒ toString()
                valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
                __defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
                __defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
                __lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
                __lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
                __proto__: Object
                    constructor: ƒ Object()
                    hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
                    isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
                    propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
                    toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
                    toString: ƒ toString()
                    valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
                    __defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
                    __defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
                    __lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
                    __lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
                    __proto__: null
                    get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
                    set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
                get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
                set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
            get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
            set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

And When I tried this :

```
obj.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__;
```

I got :

```
null
```

So I don't understand why there is more than three prototype objects in the Output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Benefits of prototypal inheritance over classical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800964/benefits-of-prototypal-inheritance-over-classical)

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it.

Comment: Maybe have a read about [JavaScript Object prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)? They make it possible to patch code of objects you inherit from. If you just ask yourself *"why is this self-referencial 3 times?"* stop yourself and understand it in broad strokes. There are three prototype objects because the language doesn't lie to you. It's just how many there are for a function. Why is this a problem in your case?

Comment: It's not a problem,like I said it's just I can't Understand why I am getting this ouptut.Are `[[Prototype]]` and `__proto__` the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

> So I don't understand why there is more than three prototype objects
> in the Output.

It's because the `SimpleFunction()` constructor function is the derivative source object ([functions are objects with prototypes too](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)). Since `SimpleFunction()` is user defined, it must inherit from the Object object just like every other object does.  Therefore you have the function object and its prototype the Object object, and then you have `obj` that is derived from the constructor with it's own Object object prototype.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#description)

If interested, here is the [spec that describes this process](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-ordinarycreatefromconstructor)

And no, [[Prototype]] and `__proto__` are not the same thing. If you look at the log, you will see setter and getters named `__proto__`. So `__proto__` is actually an accessor property for [[Prototype]] while [[Prototype]] reflects the actual object that *is* the prototype.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto#description)