# What is the difference between OOP in JS and Java?

Tags: java, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the advantages that prototype based OO has over class based OO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879061/what-are-the-advantages-that-prototype-based-oo-has-over-class-based-oo)

What is the exact difference between prototypical inheritance in js and classical inheritance in java?

Comment: They are completely different. I suggest you learn prototypical inheritance from scratch and not try to relate it to classical inheritance.

Comment: Edited the question title. Nobody outside of India [has ever heard of "OOPS"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/33299/whats-oops-is-that-term-in-use)

Comment: There are two books you want to read one is http://www.amazon.com/Pro-JavaScript-MooTools-Mark-Obcena/dp/1430230541/ the other is http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742 Neither book is particularly easy but will give you a good idea of JS both ways and why in the middle is the best place to be. DO nt JUST search for the books on Google with PDF at the end of their names.