# Which are advantages of JavaScript being prototype-based rather than object-oriented

Tags: javascript

I am a JavaScript developer for a few years and from time to time I hear that JavaScript is so great because it is prototype-based. But, when writing a big JavaScript application I constantly find myself simulating the object-oriented behavior.

One issue might be that, as Douglas Crockford said it, "JavaScript itself is conflicted about its prototypal nature" (http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html). JavaScript is the only prototype-based language I worked with.

Also I know that a proposal exists to add classes in the next EcmaScript version (http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:classes).

Don't get me wrong, I love JavaScript. I just want to understand which are the advantages of prototype-based over OOP, if any.

Comment: OOP != class-based OOP

Comment: This question has been asked before on a [programmers.se]. Here it is: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110936/what-are-the-advantages-of-prototype-based-oop-over-class-based-oop

Comment: exact duplicate of [What are the advantages that prototype based OO has over class based OO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879061/what-are-the-advantages-that-prototype-based-oo-has-over-class-based-oo)